# Mulesoft EC2 *describeInstances* with *filter* option

Tags: amazon-ec2, mule, mule-studio, mulesoft

I'm having problems using the EC2 connector with filters for DescribeInstances. Specifically, I'm trying to find all instances that have the tag "classId" set.

I've also tried to find all instances that have the classId tag with specific string, e.g. "123".

Below are the XMLs of the describeInstance for both scenarios.

tag-key ------

```
<ec2:describe-instances doc:name="Describe instances" doc:id="ca64b7d4-99bb-4045-bbb4-16c0c27b1df5" config-ref="Amazon_EC2_Configuration">
            <ec2:filters>
                <ec2:filter name="tag-key" values="#[['classId']]">
                </ec2:filter>
            </ec2:filters>
</ec2:describe-instances>
```

---

tag:classId:----

```
    <ec2:describe-instances doc:name="Describe instances" doc:id="ca64b7d4-99bb-4045-bbb4-16c0c27b1df5" config-ref="Amazon_EC2_Configuration">
                <ec2:filters>
                    <ec2:filter name="tag:classId">
                        <ec2:values >
                            <ec2:value value="#['123']" />
                        </ec2:values>
                    </ec2:filter>
                </ec2:filters>
   </ec2:describe-instances>
```

---

Each time I receive an error like the following (for tag:classId):

```
ERROR 2021-03-29 08:32:49,693 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [ec2-play].ec2-playFlow.BLOCKING @1092a5bc] [processor: ; event: df5e2df0-908a-11eb-94b5-38f9d38da5c3] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message        : The filter 'null' is invalid (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 33e3bbfb-99ea-4382-932f-647662810c92; Proxy: null)
Element        : ec2-playFlow/processors/0 @ ec2-play:ec2-play.xml:33 (Describe instances)
Element DSL      : <ec2:describe-instances doc:name="Describe instances" doc:id="ca64b7d4-99bb-4045-bbb4-16c0c27b1df5" config-ref="Amazon_EC2_Configuration">
<ec2:filters>
<ec2:filter name="tag:classId">
<ec2:values>
<ec2:value value="#['123']"></ec2:value>
</ec2:values>
</ec2:filter>
</ec2:filters>
</ec2:describe-instances>
Error type      : EC2:INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE
FlowStack       : at ec2-playFlow(ec2-playFlow/processors/0 @ ec2-play:ec2-play.xml:33 (Describe instances))

 (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

NOTE: The code works without a filter, returning all instances. But, that isn't what I want or need. The more filtering I can do the faster the response.

Does anyone have samples of the filter option working? Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This surely is a bug. I tried the same and it was not working for me as well. I enabled debug logging and found that the connector is not sending the `filter.1.Name=tag:classId` as a query parameter in the request. Here is the debug log that I found. *(Notice there is no filter.1.Name=tag:classId in the query string)*

```
DEBUG 2021-04-02 21:55:17,198 [[MuleRuntime].uber.03: [test-aws-connector].test-aws-connectorFlow.BLOCKING @2dff3afe] [processor: ; event: 91a34891-93d0-11eb-af49-606dc73d31d1] org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2016-11-15&Filter.1.Value.1=123"
```

However, I tried to use the `Expression or Bean Reference` option and set the expression directly as `[{name: 'tag:classId', values:['123']}]` like this:

[image: anypoint studio screenshot]

and it worked correctly. Here is the same debug log after this change

```
DEBUG 2021-04-02 21:59:17,198 [[MuleRuntime].uber.03: [test-aws-connector].test-aws-connectorFlow.BLOCKING @2dff3afe] [processor: ; event: 91a34891-93d0-11eb-af49-606dc73d31d1] org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2016-11-15&Filter.1.Name=tag%3AclassId&Filter.1.Value.1=123"
```

Also, I want to point out very weird behaviour, this does not work if you try to format `[{name: 'tag:classId',values: ['123']}]` across multiple lines in the expression and will give an error during deployment.

Comment: I think you should report it since you have discovered it.

Comment: THANK YOU!   I was beating my head against a wall. Now I know it isn't just me!   I will endeavor to report it, as you suggest.

Comment: Now, how to figure out how to turn on Hibernation as an additional stop action using the EC2 connector, and then hibernate and resume instances using the same.